# Why does malloc not return?

Tags: c++, c, macos, darwin

I have a thread running (OS X 10.10.5) that hangs with this stack trace. It’s after about 20 hours of operation, probably related to a low memory condition. But, the question is, why doesn’t malloc just return null? Why does the execution of the thread need to halt? The actual number of bytes requested is small (for a string operation on a path).

```
std::wstring finalPath = itsPath.substr(0,ls+1);

  1   operator new(unsigned long) + 37 (libc++abi.dylib + 124485) [0xa0339645] 2
   1   malloc + 29 (libsystem_malloc.dylib + 3997) [0xa1829f9d] 2
    1   malloc_zone_malloc + 116 (libsystem_malloc.dylib + 7243) [0xa182ac4b] 2
     1   default_zone_malloc + 3 (libsystem_malloc.dylib + 67909) [0xa1839945] 2
     *1   thread_exception_return + 0 (kernel + 632362) [0xffffff800029a62a] (runnable) 2
```

The purpose of the operation that fails is to clear out a temporary directory so the boot disk does not fill up with temporary files generated by the program. This process fails, the disk does indeed fill up, the thread halts (as in really halts, and the main thread is joined to it), and the process of deleting files off the disk stops. Also, the process has to be killed because the thread is halted. I don't know if you could exactly call this a bug since the process that fails is an attempt to prevent what actually happens.

Thank you for your insights.

Comment: *probably related to a low memory condition* -- In other words, a bug in your program.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, why on Earth? There are plenty of scenarios which lead to low memory conditions without any bugs.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are calling `malloc` directly but instead you are calling `new`.  `new` is allowed to throw unless you use `no throw` so that could be the issues.

Comment: @NathanOliver, it certainly is allowed to throw, but judging by the stack, it is not throwing, it is hanging?

Comment: *probably related* -- I get suspicious when I see those two words describe an issue, especially the "probably" part.

Comment: Not sure.  When I saw `thread_exception_return` I assumed it threw an exception.

Comment: If it appears the thread is hanging (i.e. staying alive, but not making any apparent progress) - rather than dying with an exception - it may be that it is in a busy-loop of some sort, i.e. it is repeatedly running the same code over and over again, rather than hanging. You may be able to detect this with "top" or a similar utility.

Comment: @NathanOliver, well, hard to say. It doesn't seem like this function has anything to do with C++ exception (did a cursory look at the source, but it's written in ASM for PowerPC, not my area of expertise). Also, it would be `new` to throw an exception, not `malloc` call - which again I see in the stack.

Comment: I don't think this is a C++ exception, it's returning from a kernel exception to user mode. Unfortunately, all `default_zone_malloc` does is call through a function pointer so it's very difficult to guess what it's up to.

Answer (score 0):

You mention the disk is full, so the kernel probably is trying to swap out memory to disk and failing. In this situation, macOS suspends, rather than kills out-of-control processes. The idea is that you free some space and/or close down some other applications and then resume the suspended process, for example using `kill -CONT <PID>`.

By the sound of it, the real problem is that you're allocating too much memory, or leaking memory.